# ¿Como comprobar que una variable entera no tenga mas de 9 caracteres?

Tags: java

estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el cual quiero pasar cierta cantidad de números por parámetro
aquí esta.

```
public Ejercicio2(int phonenumber) {
    this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
}
```

tengo un método en el cual quiero decirle que me imprima si phonenumber tiene mas de 9 caracteres enteros.

```
public void phone() {
    if(phonenumber > 9) {
        System.out.println("hay mas de 9 caracteres")
    }
}
```

se que lo estoy haciendo mal pero lo pongo para que por favor me corrijan.

Comment: Un int en Java no podría tener una cantidad mayor a 999999999, por lo tanto no podrias comprobar si tiene mas de 9 dígitos el entero, mi pregunta sería qué es lo que necesitas y porqué deseas realizar esa comprobación?

Comment: mira estoy haciendo este ejercicio de la universidad.(Crear una clase Persona, con atributos nombre, apellido y telefono. Controlar que el teléfono solo acepte 9 dígitos.)

Comment: Una variable entera no tiene caracteres. El número de teléfono no debería ser de tipo `int` sino de tipo `String`, debido a que, no estás haciendo calculo aritmético con dicha variable. Así se hace más fácil la comprobación de dígitos, porque simplemente usas: `phonenumber.length() > 9`  y ya...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En ese caso entonces podrias realizarlo de esta forma:

```
        String numero = "12345679";
        if(numero.length() == 9){
            System.out.println("Numero Valido");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Numero no Valido");
        }
```

Solo comprobarias que la longitud del `String` en este caso el numero de telefono no sea mayor a 9.

La segunda opcion que tienes y es la mas recomendada es que utilices expresion regular, para comprobar que en el String solo haya numeros, te dejo este ejemplo:

```
        String regEx = "^[0-9]{9}$";
        String numero = "123456789";
        if(numero.matches(regEx)){
            System.out.println("Numero Valido");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Numero no Valido");
        }
```

Comment: *La segunda opcion que tienes y es la mas recomendada es que utilices expresion regular..* ¿Por qué es la más recomendada?

Comment: muy útil gracias.

Comment: @MrDave1999 Porque asi se asegura que solo hayan numeros, porque la primer opcion si ingresan "12345678*", en efecto hay 9 caracteres pero no son solo numeros, y asi de igual forma con cualquier caracter.